# What is this unknown 10-digit device address? Found on an iPhone

Tags: network, wifi, iphone, mac-address

I saw this unknown address under my personal hotspot summary on an iPhone:

e:69:a5:97:7:17

Can this 10-digit number be a MAC address?

[image]

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253654841

Comment: Thank you very much. It makes sense. But the other problem is: what is it? From the discussion, we can see that the randomised MAC addresses are his other devices (but with missing zeros). In my case, I cannot link the randomised MAC address to any device. What do you think?

Comment: This looks very much like an EUI-48 (aka MAC address). What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: Mainly because it has 10-digits and not 12.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I do not know how to upload a screenshot here, sorry. But it was under mobile data usage --> Personal Hotspot. Then, there were two fields - one for my laptop (with its own name), using some amount of MB, and one for the unknown MAC address using precisely 9,2 KB of data. What can even 9.2 KB of data do?

Comment: Select [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/440888/edit) and then select the image - works from iOS and computers - there’s a circle with a ? To the right in edit mode with even more help…

Comment: Thank you. I have now added the screenshot. So what do you guys think?

Answer (score 3):

On Apple platforms, I’ve never had issues with the leading 0 being dropped by formatters that developers use or entering them in fields.

e:69:a5:97:7:17 and 0e:69:a5:97:07:17 are the same values

These are [hexadecimal representation of numbers and not text strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies a lot! Apparently, this has happened on Apple platforms, as was mentioned by a previous comment: discussions.apple.com/thread/253654841 , but still... no idea what/who was actually connected to my hotspot.

Comment: Apple lets iCloud devices automatically join based on shared secrets. Do you use the same iCloud and between devices and one device might have joined @randomizedcontrol_932

Comment: No, I have only activated iCloud on my iPhone. And no other devices have used this hotspot before...

Comment: @randomizedcontrol_932 Your Apple devices can share wifi login information even if iCloud is not activated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "e:69:a5:97:7:17" is a MAC-address. You would perhaps more commonly see it written as:

```
0E:69:A5:97:07:17
```

MAC-address of this type are always 48-bits long. They're commonly represented as 6 numbers (0-255) represented in hexadecimal and separated by colons. Similarly to how you can write ordinary base-10 numbers, leading zeroes in each hexadecimal number can be left out.

The digit E in "0E" means that the address is a locally administered, unicast address.

That an address is locally administered means that it is assigned locally on this particular network, and only has a meaning on this particular network.

In contrast, a globally administered address is typically assigned by the manufacturer of a device, and would be valid across networks. Such an address can typically be traced to a device manufacturer, such as for example Apple, or a network interface microchip manufacturer, such as for example Realtek.

Basically this means that this MAC-address could really be any device on this local network - you would have to check your devices to know, which one it is. In your setup it is typically a phone, tablet, or similar.